# No tests found. Cypress could not detect tests in this file for cypress version 10.2.0

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have followed the steps mentioned in the official link("https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor") to implement BDD framework using cucumber and cypress  but my test are not appearing in automation window , can anyone please help to resolve the issue?
[automation Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxsz3.jpg)

cypress.config.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const webpack = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              exclude: [/node_modules/],
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "ts-loader",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              test: /\.feature$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack",
                  options: config,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    })
  );

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

---

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "cypressjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Aninda Mondal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.2.0-rc1",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.12.0",
    "cypress": "^10.2.0"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "json": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "**/cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "**/cypress/e2e/.{js,ts}",
    "**/cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,ts}"
  ]
}
```

---

Feature file: qaweb.feature

```
Feature: Web Test
Background: Background name: Navigate to webpage
Scenarios: Web Page Navigation
When navigate to a web page
```

---

Step definition: qaweb.js

```js
 import { When } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
    /// <reference types="Cypress" />
    When("navigate to a web page", () => {
        cy.visit("https://www.duckduckgo.com");
      });
```

---

[VS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpiGe.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the feature file change `Scenarios` to `Scenario`

```js
Feature: Web Test
  Background: Background name: Navigate to webpage
  Scenario: Web Page Navigation
    When navigate to a web page
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see in your `cypress.config.js` is the presence of `setupNodeEvents`. This should be function, something like this, or you can remove it if you don't require it.

```js
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
```